# looping, get/set methods, and multiple classes, oh my

Tags: java, loops, constructor, getter-setter

I am really struggling with get/set methods. I understand the basic concept - first you set the value then you retrieve it. I am finding it rather difficult to find information about it with the minimal concepts I have already learned. I am on the 6th chapter or my first Java and programming class and it is all online. I created a couple other classes that used set/get methods, but those don't really seem to fit this project.

```
public class Purchase{
   int inv;
   double sale;
   double tax;
   double taxAmount = 0.05;

public int getInv()
{
   return inv;
}
public void setInv(int inv)
{
   inv = inv;
}

public void setSale(double s)
{
   sale = s;
   tax = sale * taxAmount;
}
public double getSale()
{
   return sale;
}

//display
public void display()
{
System.out.println("Invoice number: " + getInv() + "\nSale amount: $" + getSale() + "\nTax: $" + tax + "\nTotal: $" + (tax + sale));
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CreatePurchase{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Purchase one = new Purchase();

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   do
   {
   System.out.print("Please enter you invoice number. This will be a number between 1000 and 8000.  ");
   inv = input.nextInt();
   one.setInv(inv);
   }
   while(inv < 1000 && inv > 8000);
   {
   System.out.println("Please enter the amount of your sale.  ");
   sale = input.nextInt();
   }
}
}
```

The CreatePurchase class is not finished, but I compile it and get the below for every variable every time it appears:

```
CreatePurchase.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
      inv = input.nextInt();
      ^
```

It was my understanding that a default constructor is made, so I didn't add one, but called it in CreatePurchase. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that your `Purchase#setInv` method should be `this.inv = inv;` - otherwise you're just setting the given variable to itself.

Comment: All the inv are the same variable and refer to the same thing (invoice number). I honestly don't get why in the set method needs to say this equals that. Since I'm setting the inv in the other class I just put it as itself. As far as not declaring it again in CreatePurchase, I assumed it was taking all the info from Purchase when I did Purchase one = new Purchase; (constructor). ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problems. First, you can create a new variable with the same name as another variable that's in a bigger container (scope). In this case, the new variable "hides" or "shadows" the outer one. In your `setInv` method, when you say `inv = inv`, *both* `inv`s refer to the innermost variable, the one in the method signature. To save the argument to the class's field, you need to specify the outer `inv`: `this.inv = inv;`.

In your `CreatePurchase` class, you don't have any `inv` defined; there's one in `Purchase`, but that's over there, not here. You just need to declare `int inv;` right after your `Purchase one`.

Based on these two errors, I would recommend reading an article or tutorial about *variable scope* in Java to learn the rules about which variables are accessible where.

Comment: @KarenByk What do you mean "all the `inv` are the same variable"? You have three different ones: the field in `Purchase`, the method parameter in `Purchase#setInv`, and another `inv` over in `CreatePurchase`. And no, creating a new copy of `Purchase` doesn't "import" all of the internal state of `Purchase` into `CreatePurchase`; that's the entire idea behind **encapsulation**. A tutorial on Java variable scope will be very helpful.

Comment: I only need one invoice number. The user enters it in CreatePurchase. Purchase should contain the invoice number, sale amount, and tax. Use set methods for invoice number and sale amount and in the sale set method calculate the tax. CreatePurchase should declare a Purchase object and prompt for the detail.    I am not asking for someone to do my assignment, I'm looking for help understanding how it works.

Comment: @KarenByk I know that you only have one piece of information that is the invoice number, but that information is going to pass through several variables--first into a temporary holding variable inside your reader method, then into a transfer variable (method argument) in `setInv`, then to a field (its final destination) called `Purchase.inv`. These are all different variables, and there are specific rules about where you can refer to them and how. (I know you're trying to learn; otherwise, I'd be voting to close the question.)

Comment: So how do I get `CreatePurchase` to call the info from `Purchase`? I added `one.display();` to CreatePurchase and it shows the display from Purchase will all 0s- it doesn't pull the invoice number entered in CreatePurchse. 
Maybe variable is the wrong term, but basically there is one number that inv will be in the end. It doesn't need to change from one thing to another at any point.

Comment: @KarenByk Did you fix the `this` problem I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I did... but didn't compile it. argh! So that worked. Hooray. I still don't really get the set/get. I've read the chapters in the book (Java Programming by Joyce Farrell if you really wanted to know) like 30 times, about 200 posts, and watched many videos, but it still just doesn't click. Any book or article recommendations? I generally comprehend things quickly and get incredibly frustrated when I don't which makes matters worse.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @KarenByk I'd take you to chat, but you don't have the rep. Basically, the `get`/`set` model is to get around the fact that Java has a simpler syntax that can't name methods fun things like `inv=` in Ruby. Everyone acknowledges that it's clumsy, but it works very well for all of the tools that can automatically scan for them. If you can ask about specific things that aren't "clicking" in new questions, you can probably get helpful answers. (And please remember to upvote any answers that are useful, including the ones you accept!)

Comment: I've been checking out this forum for months but haven't joined until now, so yes the rep is prohibiting things, such as up voting. Only 7 more points to go!

Answer (score 2):

You've failed to declare the variable `inv` any where, for example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Purchase one = new Purchase();

    // !! Variable must be declared before it can be used !! //
    int inv = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter you invoice number. This will be a number between 1000 and 8000.  ");
        inv = input.nextInt();
        one.setInv(inv);
    } while (inv < 1000 && inv > 8000);
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of your sale.  ");
        // This will be your next problem...
        sale = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Your `Purchase` class is also going to have problems...

The following method is essentially assigning the value of `inv` back to itself, which is meaningless in this context...

```
public void setInv(int inv)
{
    inv = inv;
}
```

Instead, you should be assigning to the instance of the `Purchase` class's `inv` variable...

```
public void setInv(int inv)
{
    this.inv = inv;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You havent declared the variable `inv` in `main` method, at this step
`inv = input.nextInt();`
Change your program to below

```
int inv = 0;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   do
   {
   System.out.print("Please enter you invoice number. This will be a number between 1000 and 8000.  ");
   inv = input.nextInt();
   if(inv >1000 & inv <8000)
        one.setInv(inv);//add to one variable only if its correct,otherwise ignore it
   }
   while(inv < 1000 && inv > 8000);
```